# How to use Maven to create an executable jar for the src/test/java directory?

Tags: maven, jar, dependency-management

I have a project with src/main/java and src/test/java structure.  It is fairly straightforward to use the maven-assembly-plugin, the jar-with-dependencies descriptor, and the mainClass manifest in order to create a jar file that includes a main class from the src/main/java directory, and all classes on which this main class depends, such that the main class may be executed using the 'java -jar project-jar-with-dependencies.jar' command.  How might I create a similar jar file for a main class from the src/test/java directory?

Comment: what are u using. okay the best bet would be to use. mvn clean test

Comment: Default structure of maven should be: src/main/java for code, src/main/test for Unit test, if your folder structure does not match this, you have to modify the parameter when building jar.

Comment: How were you able to solve this? If you found a solution please share, it might be useful to others